# Error encountered while cloning the remote repository: Failed to mark Git repository folder as hidden:

Tags: azure-devops, visual-studio-2015, azure-repos

From Azure Devops repository webpage, I selected "Clone" and then "Visual Studio".  Visual Studio 2015 opened as expected (we have to use VS2015 for BizTalk 2016).  I clicked the "Clone" button, and the output windows shows this message:

> Error encountered while cloning the remote repository: Failed to mark
> Git repository folder as hidden:

We are setting up several new repositories, and I did the same thing last week with the same user account and it worked.  Could this be a security/permission issue with a misleading error?

Answer (score 0):

One get around is: If I open Visual Studio "as Administrator", the clone works okay.  (We often have to do this in BizTalk, as it puts its DLLs in the Global Assembly Cache (GAC), which requires Admin permissions.

I have full access to the directory, so I'm not sure why running under my account gives the error.